# Iterate over data to show autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I m trying to show Autocomplete results.

Here is the data that my script returns when I query it using a GET request

For example when I query it "fb"

It returns me the following data

```
 "fb"
 "fbi"
 "fbi most wanted"
 "fbi jobs"
 "fb banners"
 "fbook"
 "fb covers"
 "fbanners"
 "fbisd"
 "fbop"
```

Here's the code for the Autocomplete plugin

```
        $("#query").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "q.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "q" : request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                response(data[1])
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
```

It doesnt show me any result. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong here!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#query").autocomplete({
        source: "q.php",
        minLength: 2
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li></li>")
            .append("<a>" + item+ "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery Autocomplete plugin, why would you over-complicate it and render it by yourself?

Just define a source script and provide a well formated JSON response as the Autocomplete module wants it:

> Expected data format
>
> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:
>
> An Array of Strings:
>   [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
>
> An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
>   [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

```
source: "query.php";
```

Let the plugin to do the rest.

Read the API: [jQuery Autocomplete plugin overview](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete)

If you want to do anything else, just register for and catch an event.